# In memcached, you can put a List as a value. Can you put a list in beanstalkd?

Tags: list, dictionary, queue, memcached, beanstalkd

Actually, I would like to use this for logging.
I want to put a dictionary into beanstalkd.

Everytime someone goes into my website, I want to put a dictionary into beanstalkd, and then every night, I want a script that will get all the jobs and stick them in the database.

THis will make it fast and easy.

Comment: Please clarify the question.  This is more of a nonsense ramble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a large upper limit on the size of each job in beanstalk (>2MB) but performance does seem to be adversely affected at that point. If the size of the dictionary is large you probably want to store the actual dictionary in a SQL table and store the ID of that row in the job, then have the worker retrieve the SQL row when it grabs the job that has the correlated ID.